# JUnit Tests for Liferay MVCPortlet using PowerMock

Tags: unit-testing, junit, liferay, mockito, powermock

Im trying to make JUnit Test using PowerMock, but I have one problem. Here is my code:

```
public class MyGreeting extends MVCPortlet {

    public static final String GREETING="greeting";
    private static final String DEFAULT_GREETING="MY DEFAULT GREETING MESSAGE";
    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyGreeting.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void render(RenderRequest req,RenderResponse res) 
            throws IOException, PortletException {
        PortletPreferences prefs = req.getPreferences();
        req.setAttribute(GREETING, prefs.getValue(GREETING, DEFAULT_GREETING));
        super.render(req,res);
    }
```

And I need to make JUnit test. I created another test package, new MyGreetingTest.java file, and come up to this code:

```
public class MyGreetingTest extends Mockito{

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

private MyGreeting portlet;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    portlet = new MyGreeting();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Mock
public RenderRequest request = mock(RenderRequest.class);

@Mock
PortletPreferences preferences = mock(PortletPreferences.class);


@Test
public final void renderTest() throws IOException, PortletException {

    when(request.getPreferences()).thenReturn(preferences);
    when(preferences.getValue(MyGreeting.GREETING, null)).thenReturn(value);

    portlet.render(request, null);
    String result = request.getAttribute(MyGreeting.GREETING).toString();
    assertEquals(result, value);
}
```

But I have NullPointerException, because we can't apply `getAttribute` method to `mock-request`. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? How can I test method with `getAttribute` method using Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mock your method

> Stock stock = mock(Stock.class);
>   when(stock.getPrice()).thenReturn(100.00);    // Mock implementation
>   when(stock.getValue()).thenCallRealMethod();  // Real implementation

Comment: That's something weird. You suggest to paste this code  instead of `when/thenReturn` block?

Comment: Nope, I just suggested you how to mock the method!